# Can I add custom metadata types to razor views?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I use an abstract class inheriting from `WebViewPage` to provide functions to razor views in my MVC project. We're using a custom Login class/solution. My class looks like this:

```
public abstract class AuthenticatedViewPageBase : WebViewPage
{
    private Login _user;

    protected override void InitializePage()
    {
        _user = Session["User"] as Login;
    }

    public bool HasPermission(Permissions permission)
    {
        return HasPermission(new List<Permissions> { permission });
    }
    public bool HasPermission(List<Permissions> permissions)
    {
        if (_user == null)
            _user = Session["User"] as Login;

        return _user != null && permissions.Any(thisPerm => _user.Permissions.Any(p => p.PermissionId == (int)thisPerm));
    }

    public bool HasPermission(List<Permissions> permissions, List<PermissionGroups> groups)
    {
        if (_user == null)
            _user = Session["User"] as Login;

        return _user != null &&
            (
                permissions.Any(thisPerm => _user.Permissions.Any(p => p.PermissionId == (int)thisPerm))
                ||
                groups.Any(thisPerm => _user.Permissions.Any(p => p.PermissionGroupId == (int)thisPerm))
            );
    }
}
```

My views look like this:

```
@using PublicationSystem.Model.Enums
@model IEnumerable<PublicationSystem.Model.Profile>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSmBanner.cshtml";
}

@if (HasPermission(new List<Permissions>
{
    Permissions.userCreate
}))
{
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
}
```

This works okay, but I'd love to be able to clean it up. I would love to have a property in my AuthenticatedViewPageBase and create an enhanced ActionLink so that I could so something like this:

```
public abstract class AuthenticatedViewPageBase : WebViewPage
{
    //...
    public List<Permissions> ViewPermissions { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@using PublicationSystem.Model.Enums
@model IEnumerable<PublicationSystem.Model.Profile>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSmBanner.cshtml";
}

<p>
    @Html.SecureActionLink("Create New", "Create") // checks the @permissions metadata
</p>
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@model PublicationSystem.Model.Profile
@ViewPermissions new List<Permissions> {Permissions.userCreate} // This would be the custom 
     // property or metadata field I define in the abstract class

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Profile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSmBanner.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ...
}
```

If I could do this, my links would only need to ask the target View which permissions are required, instead of having to wrap an if statement around each link.

Can I add attributes/properties to my abstract WebViewPage class to decorate a view like my example? If so how?

Would it be possible for a custom ActionLink to 'look' at the target View's meta data?

***Edit:***
I may be looking for something like this:

```
[Authorize(Permission="userCreate")]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //...
}
```

But I would want to be Permission level, not Role level, and I would want to enable my links to be hidden/visible based on the user having the necessary permission.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily accomplish this with a custom HTML helper. Here is an example `SecureLink` that accepts a roles parameter. If the user is logged in and in any role specified, then the link will be visible, otherwise it will be invisible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName)
    {
        return htmlHelper.SecureLink(linkText, roles, actionName, null, 
            new RouteValueDictionary(), new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName, object routeValues)
    {
        return htmlHelper.SecureLink(linkText, roles, actionName, null, 
            new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        return htmlHelper.SecureLink(linkText, roles, actionName, controllerName, 
            new RouteValueDictionary(), new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        return htmlHelper.SecureLink(linkText, roles, actionName, null, 
            routeValues, new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return htmlHelper.SecureLink(linkText, roles, actionName, null, 
            new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), 
            HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, 
        IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        return htmlHelper.SecureLink(linkText, roles, actionName, null, 
            routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName, string controllerName, 
        object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return htmlHelper.SecureLink(linkText, roles, actionName, controllerName, 
            new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), 
            HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName, string controllerName, 
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("linkText");
        }
        if (!htmlHelper.IsInAnyRole(roles))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create("");
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, htmlHelper.RouteCollection, linkText, 
            null, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName, string controllerName, string protocol, 
        string hostName, string fragment, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return htmlHelper.SecureLink(linkText, roles, actionName, controllerName, 
            protocol, hostName, fragment, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), 
            HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, 
        string roles, string actionName, string controllerName, string protocol, 
        string hostName, string fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, 
        IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("linkText");
        }
        if (!htmlHelper.IsInAnyRole(roles))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create("");
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, htmlHelper.RouteCollection, linkText, 
            null, actionName, controllerName, protocol, hostName, fragment, routeValues, 
            htmlAttributes));
    }

    private static bool IsInAnyRole(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string roles)
    {
        var user = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (user == null || user.Identity == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(roles))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return user.IsInAnyRole(SplitString(roles));
    }

    private static bool IsInAnyRole(this IPrincipal user, IEnumerable<string> roles)
    {
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            if (user.IsInRole(role))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static string[] SplitString(string original)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
        {
            return new string[0];
        }

        var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                    let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                    where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                    select trimmed;
        return split.ToArray();
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
@Html.SecureLink("Logged In Users Will See This", "", "About", "Home")
@Html.SecureLink("Admins and Managers Will See This", "Admin,Manager", "About", "Home")
@Html.ActionLink("Everyone Will See This", "About", "Home")
```

Another option is to use [MvcSiteMapProvider's security trimming feature](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming), which will automatically use the `AuthorizeAttribute` (or any subclass of it) to control the visibility of navigation links.

> **FULL DISCLOSURE:** I am a major contributor of the `MvcSiteMapProvider` project.

But however you get the job done, you should be using the built-in `IPrincipal` and `IIdendity` interfaces and `AuthorizeAttribute` of MVC rather than reinventing the wheel. You could easily extend the `AuthorizeAttribute` to use any permission scheme.

Adding this extra clutter to a view base class is not a good approach.

Comment: That's good, but I would still have to list the permissions/roles in the link. I would like the link to look at the View, and have the view define it's own permissions.

Comment: Authorization is not the responsibility of the view. It is the responsibility of [authorzation filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) (`AuthorizeAttribute` is one of them). The problem with hiding links is that you are not actually providing any security for the action methods (the public endpoints). The write-once approach is to define your permissions with an authorization filter and then have the  custom HTML helper use that authorization filter to determine whether the link should be visible.

Comment: That is the approach that is taken in the [AuthorizeAttributeAclModule](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Security/AuthorizeAttributeAclModule.cs) of `MvcSiteMapProvider`.